# Using Webdriver with Chrome — missing Shared Libraries

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, google-chrome

I am trying to run webdriver, but I keep getting the following error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-30-0-41 ~]$ sudo ./chromedriver 
./chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: 
 libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to yum this missing dependencies? Or what seems to be the issue here? This is using the Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09.1 (HVM) Distribution.

Comment: Try something other than Amazon Linux. It's not a very well built distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody compiled a library here https://plus.google.com/u/0/wm/1/111764273672221448826 but it would be safer to do it on your own.